# Regularity of solutions of strongly elliptic system: how smooth must the boundary be?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded domain with the boundary of class $C^{1,1}$. 
Let $A$ be a selfadjoint operator acting in $L^2(\Omega;\mathbb{C}^n)$. 
The operator $A$ is given by the differential expression 
$b(D)^* g^0 b(D)$ with the Dirichlet boundary condition.
The domain of $A$ is $H^2(\Omega;\mathbb{C}^n)\cap H^1_0(\Omega;\mathbb{C}^n)$.
Here $g^0$ is a constant Hermitian positive definite $(m\times m)$-matrix;
$b(D)= \sum_{l=1}^d b_l D_l$ is a first order differential operator, where $b_l$ are constant $(m\times n)$-matrices.
It is assumed that $m \ge n$ and the symbol $b(\xi) = \sum_{l=1}^d b_l \xi_l$
is subject to the condition 
$$
{\rm rank}\, b(\xi) =n,\ \ 0\ne \xi \in \mathbb{R}^d,
$$
which ensures that $A$ is strongly elliptic.

It is known that $A$ is continuous from $H^s(\Omega;\mathbb{C}^n)$ to $H^{s+2}(\Omega;\mathbb{C}^n)$ for integer $s\ge 0$
if $\partial \Omega \in C^{s+1,1}$. This follows from the results about regularity of solutions of strongly elliptic systems.
We can refer to [McLean, Chapter 4].

QUESTION: is this true for non-integer $s>0$? 
The (optimal) condition of smoothness of  $\partial \Omega$ is of interest.
What is the reference?

The same question for the case of the Neumann boundary condition is interesting too.

[McLean]  McLean W., *Strongly elliptic systems and boundary integral equations*, Cambridge: Cambridge Univ. Press, 2000.

Comment: You can substitute a Sobolev type regularity for the assumption that $\partial\Omega$ is $C^{s+1,1}$. Mazya's book is a good reference for regularity results under optimal assumptions.

Comment: @Michael Renardy: thank you! Which Mazya's book do you mean?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy: Michael, I know that this an old post, but would you please elaborate on which Mazya reference you have in mind? I think it might be relevant for me. Thank you.